# How to fix Python ValueError:bad marshal data?

Tags: python

Running flexget Python script in Ubuntu, I get an error:

```
$ flexget series forget "Orange is the new black" s03e01
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/bin/flexget", line 7, in <module>
from flexget import main
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flexget/__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
from flexget.manager import Manager
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flexget/manager.py", line 21, in <module>
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/ext/declarative/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
from .api import declarative_base, synonym_for, comparable_using, \
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/ext/declarative/api.py", line 11, in <module>
from ...orm import synonym as _orm_synonym, \
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
from .mapper import (
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/mapper.py", line 27, in <module>
from . import properties
ValueError: bad marshal data (unknown type code)
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this Q should be migrated to SO or SU. It's asking for help with Python but `flextget` would seem to be a better fit over on SU.

Comment: I've fixed this type of error by deleting the local .pyc files in the folders listed above. The error is due to a corrupted compiled python file somewhere in there

Answer (score 153, accepted):

If you get that error, the compiled version of the Python module (the .pyc file) is corrupt probably. Gentoo Linux provides `python-updater`, but in Debian the easier way to fix: just delete the .pyc file. If you don't know the pyc, just delete all of them (as root):

```
find /usr -name '*.pyc' -delete
```

Comment: Can we make this the accepted answer @Jamie-m? It's much more general.

Comment: Of course this works but is really the wrong approach. It is like cutting of all limbs to stop gangrene, in case there is gangrene in one little toe. A normal user **cannot** recreate the `.pyc` files in these directories. That means loading Python programs by users will be slower, most likely forever, as this is done from `.py` files, since `.pyc` files will not be recreated until some root (or some other user with write permission) runs Python programs that load **all of the python modules for all of the python versions installed under** `/usr`, which is unlikely to happen.

Comment: @Anthon yes, good point but I'm not a _normal_ user. I'm the admin (root) user. Removing all `.pyc` files is not the most elegant solution but I don't know how many files are corrupt actually. I could be the `mapper.pyc` file, the full sqlalchemy module or whatever. The byte code generation time is insignificant for me (even for my Raspberry Pi 3).

Comment: This helped me immensely thank you. I had a drive get full while running and I just couldn't find the corrupt py lib.

Comment: I had moved a directory and I got this error. This fixed the directory immediately.

Answer (score 32):

There also appears to have been some sort of regression in setuptools with use with python 3.7. See for an example - https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/1257

Forcing reinstallation of setuptools fixed this issue for me.

```
sudo pip3 install --upgrade --force-reinstall setuptools
```

Comment: I know this sort of thing is discouraged on stackoverflow but: "Thank you!"

Comment: I get the same bad marshal data error when running this force reinstall....

Answer (score 19):

Just delete

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/properties.pyc
```

it is corrupt as the text indicates. You'll probably have to do so as `root`.

After that start (again as root) run python (2.7):

```
/usr/bin/python -c "import sqlalchemy.orm.properties"
```

to recreate this `.pyc` file.

If you don't recreate the `.pyc` file, your program starts slower than necessary as the `.py` file takes longer to load than the `.pyc` (and a normal user cannot write the `.pyc` file).

Comment: Is there a way to create all .pyc s? (without manually importing them)

Comment: @FábioDias Try `python -m compileall -h` and provide the correct arguments (possible none).

Answer (score 6):

This can happen if you have Python 2.7 .pyc files and you try to load them using Python 3.5.  In my case this was a third-party tarball that erroneously included pre-compiled Python 2.7 .pyc files along with the source code.

Answer (score 4):

I get this error in `Ubuntu 18.04` **Raspberry Pi 3** when I trying update my system typing `sudo apt-get update` and solve this error just typing:

`sudo find /usr -name '*.pyc' -delete`

This is remove all `.pyc` file in my system. Now I typing again `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` and I get my update without thie error `marshal-data`

Comment: I got the error message using borg and the answer worked fine!

Comment: Worked for me also.  I suspect that some of the other "uninstall and reinstall it" answers to this question work because they are, in the process, automatically deleting old *.pyc files.

Answer (score 2):

I resolved a similar error by un-installing and re-installing the Python application I was using, and all dependencies, using the system package manager.

In my case I was using awscli on Debian 9 and the error was "ValueError: bad marshal data (set size out of range)".

I ran as root:

```
apt-get purge awscli
apt-get autoremove
apt-get install awscli
```

And then the error was fixed.

I could imagine cases where the broken package might not get removed (for example because it was marked as manually installed, or was a dependency of another application still installed), in those cases this action may not resolve the error. However I thought I should try this way before manually deleting .pyc files the system installed, and I got lucky.

Answer (score 1):

I also got this problem in Windows environment(win 10).

I fixed it by going to the Settings and repairing Python 3.7 with its installer.
Everything works fine since then.

As far as I could recall, I had kept a dash server running when my computer went to hibernation.
Maybe the damage was done in the hibernating process somehow.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by the following procedure :

In the error code message, you can see
`from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base` cause this error.

So just `pip uninstall sqlalchemy` and `pip install sqlalchemy`, problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

It may be because of the damage of the library. Try re-install the package.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error in a conda environment which traced back to importing the matplotlib package.

simply `pip uninstall matplotlib` and then `pip install matplotlib` solved the problem.

Comment: Similar except it was Pandas and that didn't work but installing a different version worked. Went from 1.5.3 to 1.5.2