# Not able to uninstall python from my ubuntu machine , multiple python version installed on the server

Tags: python, ubuntu

```
ValueError: bad marshal data (unknown type code)
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/python3-distupgrade_1%3a0.220.9_all.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/apturl-common_0.5.2ubuntu4_armhf.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Ubuntu comes with Python installed and it is a necessary system application. What reason do you have to uninstall it?

Comment: M not able to upgrade my  server, it is giving me "ValueError: bad marshal data (unknown type code) " this error, how do i remove this error.

Comment: The comment here seems to think that this works on Debian systems. http://stackoverflow.com/a/30861494/2308683

Comment: Deleted the required file in the link, error is still the same...!!! :(

Comment: You could try clearing out the apt cache... I don't really know what to tell you, though. Been too long since using Ubuntu. I switched because updates always seem to break the system

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, after Python is uninstalled from Ubuntu - you need to reinstall Ubuntu. check this [link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/148383/how-to-resolve-dpkg-error-processing-var-cache-apt-archives-python-apport-2-0)