# can't remove python pip

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi, pip

i've installed both python3 and python
it used to work everything perfect
but today i encountered several issues with **pip**

then i tried to uninstall it and install it again
i've made

```
sudo apt-get remove pip
sudo apt-get remove pip3
sudo apt-get purge pip
sudo apt-get purge pip3
sudo apt-get remove python-setuptools
sudo apt-get remove python3-setuptools
```

and
when i write down "pip"
at the prompt i still have this error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pip==9.0.1', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 356, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2476, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2190, in load
    ['__name__'])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pip-9.0.1-py3.4.egg/pip/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions import DependencyWarning
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pip-9.0.1-py3.4.egg/pip/_vendor/requests/__init__.py", line 65, in <module>
    from . import utils
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pip-9.0.1-py3.4.egg/pip/_vendor/requests/utils.py", line 22, in <module>
    from . import certs
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1200, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1129, in _exec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1467, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1570, in get_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 656, in _compile_bytecode
ValueError: bad marshal data (unknown type code)
```

what do you suggest?
thanks

Comment: `python -m pip uninstall pip setuptools`

Comment: `pip uninstall python-pip`

Comment: `/usr/local/bin/pip` isn't a location where system packages would install it. Did you install a different version pip not managed by the packaging system, or use pip to upgrade itself? If so those are not managed by apt, so you can't uninstall them using apt. Everything in `/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages` should be stuff installed using `sudo pip` or pip as root, which can conflict with the system python installation. You may have to delete stuff there manually. Its usually better to use a virtualenv instead of using `sudo pip` to install packages.

Comment: after few days i kinda fixed the problem. It was a broken wrong installation actually in /usr/local/bin... i removed that manually... and then i reinstalled pip and pip3 with apt-get and now everything work fine. probably i've done a funky installation on the first time... that's explaining why i still need to make "sudo pip" to installa modules... anyway now seems to work fine. thanks everybody

Answer (score 24):

you need to execute the following command to install pip
`sudo apt-get install python3-pip`

and to remove you need to use
`sudo apt-get --purge autoremove python3-pip`

Comment: WARNING! It removed cuda as well from my system!

Answer (score 13):

I had the same problem, but I solved using the command below:

```
sudo python -m pip uninstall pip
```

Comment: you save my time！

Answer (score 1):

Pip is in package [python-pip](https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/python-pip) or [python3-pip](https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/python/python3-pip) if we are talking about python 3. You can't uninstall it with `sudo apt-get remove pip`. And when it comes to the traceback you got, check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30861493/how-to-fix-python-valueerrorbad-marshal-data).

Answer (score 0):

If you are a Windows user, make sure you run 'python -m pip uninstall pip' in admin mode. Hope that helps.