# How uninstall pip3

Tags: python, pip, erpnext

I am having some problems with pip when trying to install a python application.
It says its not able to find pip3, but its installed

Digging deeper I think I have locations where pip3 is installed.

While trying to uninstall, even that is not working since it referring to the other pip3

How to I go about keeping only one copy of pip3 and uninstall one copy of it

```
$which pip3
/home/frappeuser/.local/bin/pip3

$ sudo pip3 uninstall pip
sudo: unable to execute /usr/local/bin/pip3: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Try removing the `pip3` files manually? Then, simply reinstall it from the website. That's what worked for me a while ago on Windows, not sure about (Kali) Linux.

Comment: Check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43847317/cant-remove-python-pip

Comment: Does this answer your question? [can't remove python pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43847317/cant-remove-python-pip)

Comment: Check this one also: [I screwed up the system version of Python Pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16237490/i-screwed-up-the-system-version-of-python-pip-on-ubuntu-12-10)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can unninstall it using python in cmd using the following:

```
python3 -m pip uninstall pip
```

In case you are using python 2.0

```
python -m pip uninstall pip
```

`python` - refers to the python version that you are working with

`-m` - refers to the option `module`

`pip` - specifies the module name that you want to use

`uninstall` - the operation you want to do

`pip` - the module that you want to uninstall

Answer (score 0):

`/local/` means you have it installed not via package manager, so to uninstall it you have to provide the full path:

```
sudo /home/frappeuser/.local/bin/pip3 uninstall pip
```