# ValueError: bad marshal data in python scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I have already successfully installed scrapy in my computer(win7,32bit). when I ran my code,my program crashed with the error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "E:/python/wheather/whethercode.py", line 1, in <module>
    import scrapy
    File "F:\Program Files\python\lib\site-packages\scrapy-1.3.3-py2.7.egg\scrapy\__init__.py", line 34, in <module>
    from scrapy.spiders import Spider
    File "F:\Program Files\python\lib\site-packages\scrapy-1.3.3-py2.7.egg\scrapy\spiders\__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from scrapy.http import Request
    File "F:\Program Files\python\lib\site-packages\scrapy-1.3.3-py2.7.egg\scrapy\http\__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from scrapy.http.request.form import FormRequest
    File "F:\Program Files\python\lib\site-packages\scrapy-1.3.3-py2.7.egg\scrapy\http\request\form.py", line 9, in <module>
    import lxml.html
    ValueError: bad marshal data (unknown type code)
```

Hope you can help me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix Python ValueError:bad marshal data?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30861493/how-to-fix-python-valueerrorbad-marshal-data)

Comment: http://support.esri.com/technical-article/000011731