# ValueError: bad marshal not solved by deleting .pyc files?

Tags: python

So I'm getting a long error when trying to run some python code. It starts at importing a function from sklearn, and ends like this:

```
  File "/home/richard/Projects/ast01oger/ast1_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scipy/linalg/__init__.py", line 194, in <module>
    from .misc import *
  File "/home/richard/Projects/ast01oger/ast1_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scipy/linalg/misc.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .lapack import get_lapack_funcs
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 779, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 911, in get_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 580, in _compile_bytecode
ValueError: bad marshal data (invalid reference)
```

Well, I looked it up, apparently the thing is to do is to delete the .pyc files in the relevant folders, but I did that, and nothing changes. Looking at [this previously asked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30861493/how-to-fix-python-valueerrorbad-marshal-data), I would expect there to be a lapack.pyc file in .../lib/python3.8/site-packages/scipy/linalg/, but there aren't any .pyc file there at all, only a lapack.py, which I don't think I'm meant to delete.

Also, the end of my error is a bit different from the error in the other question, as you might have noticed; what does this mean? Is there a .pyc file I haven't actually deleted, in another location?

Answer (score 0):

Whatever it was, it was a problem with one of the scipy files. I tried re-installing sklearn because it was an sklearn function that broke everything, seemingly, but as you can see and as I saw later the problem was actually with scipy; reinstalling the whole library did the trick.