# Tensorflow not loading facenet model

Tags: tensorflow, keras, facenet

This is an error i am getting on spyder 5.0.3

> File
> "C:\Users\HP\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\layers\core.py",
> line 1057, in _parse_function_from_config
> function = generic_utils.func_load(
>
> File
> "C:\Users\HP\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\utils\generic_utils.py",
> line 457, in func_load
> code = marshal.loads(raw_code)
>
> ValueError: bad marshal data (unknown type code)

library-versions:
[image]

I have tried downgrading my libraries.. but nothing has happened

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras


model_path = 'facenet_keras.h5'
#model = load_model(model_path)

#model = tf.keras.models.load_model(model_path)

#model = keras.models.load_model(model_path)

tf.keras.models.load_model(
    model_path, custom_objects=None, compile=True, options=None
)
```

tried all this!

Comment: This doesn't seem to be related to `tensorflow`.  [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30861493/how-to-fix-python-valueerrorbad-marshal-data) might be related. I suggest you to force a reinstall of setuptools in your Anaconda environment.

Comment: Where did you get the facenet model from?

Comment: I have tried to reinstall setup tools but nothing happened... and to answer the second question here is the link to the model https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/12aMYASGCKvDdkygSv1yQq8ns03AStDO_