# Python problems on RaspberryPI

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I am using Python 3 on Raspberry PI and after a proper shutdown and power on of the system again I noticed that Python is no longer working. Note that it took several attempts to properly boot Raspberry PI (power on/off) due to a reason I am not sure of yet. After the boot I tried launching a custom program and the Python interpreter itself. In both cases I got `ValueError: bad marshal data (unknown type code)` I referred to the steps provided here to fix that problem: [How to fix Python ValueError:bad marshal data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30861493/how-to-fix-python-valueerrorbad-marshal-data)

What I did is as follows:

1. `sudo find /usr -name '*.pyc' -delete` without sudo I cannot delete
2. `sudo update` && `sudo upgrade`

> pi@raspberrypi:~ $ python3 Fatal Python error: initsite: Failed to
> import the site module Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/usr/lib/python3.7/site.py", line 79, in 
> import os   File "/usr/lib/python3.7/os.py", line 191
> def makedirs(name, mode=0o777, exist_ok=False):
> """makedirs(name [, mode=0o777][, exist_ok=False])
> ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax

I am not able to resolve this issue. Do you have any suggestions? Can it be related with a symbolic link pointing the wrong direction or a file corruption?

Comment: It indeed does sound like file corruption. Could you do a fresh install again?

Comment: Do you mean a complete reinstall of the operating system?

Comment: yes. I know this is not the solution you'd like to hear, but IMO, it's better to be safe than sorry. There might be more corrupt files which you don't know of. Also, for this exact reason, I suggest you get an external drive and backup your files there.

Comment: Okay thanks, I will change the SD card with a spare one and purchase another SD card in the meantime.