# keras ValueError: bad marshal data (unknown type code)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am having difficulty while I want to test the model I created from another computer.

My code for running model is :

```
import tensorflow.keras.models as M

org_net = M.load_model(route_net, compile=True, custom_objects={'B': keras.backend,'diceloss':diceloss})
```

and Here I got an error which I could not see when I tried at other pc.

```
File "C:\Users\Euijeong Song\PycharmProjects\dl_nxb\venv\test_org.py", line 30, in <module>
org_net = M.load_model(route_net, compile=True, custom_objects={'B': keras.backend,'diceloss':diceloss})#
File "C:\Users\Euijeong Song\PycharmProjects\dl_nxb\venv\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 67, in error_handler
raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
File "C:\Users\Euijeong Song\PycharmProjects\dl_nxb\venv\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\generic_utils.py", line 792, in func_load
code = marshal.loads(raw_code)
ValueError: bad marshal data (unknown type code)
```

My python version is 3.9.0 and tf == 2.7.0. And the model was created where python == 3.6.8 and tf ==2.1.0. I found that the marshal error occurs when using python==2.x.x but I don't understand this time. why does this happen and how can I solve this ?

Comment: Does this answer to your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30861493/how-to-fix-python-valueerrorbad-marshal-data

Comment: @Jamjitul Does this work for window environment? I use window /pycham setup

Comment: you seems to be using pycharm, there in First option, clear cache and restart. Should work.

Comment: @AnuragDhadse I cleared cache and restarted but same error still occurs. Can you please tell me why you suggested the way ?

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem. It was because of python and cudnn version was too high yet.

I downgraded cudnn to 8.2.2, which is for cuda 11.4, and python to 3.7.0