# Facenet_keras: (ValueError: bad marshal data (unknown type code))

Tags: tensorflow, keras, face-recognition, facenet

I am new to the TensorFlow and Keras , I want to implement the Facenet_keras model which can be found in this link (https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1pwQ3H4aJ8a6yyJHZkTwtjcL4wYWQb7bn)
I keep getting the error ValueError: bad marshal data (unknown type code)

I think it may be a version compatibility error, since I am using Keras and Tensorflow version 2.12 and python version 3.10.
The problem is I am using google colab and I cannot downgrade to a version of tensorflow below 2.8 and a version of python below 3.8.

Whilst I did try it out on those downgraded versions above. They don’t work.

Please can someone help me out or guide me on what other solution I could use to fix my issue.

I want to load the model to use it for facial recognition

Comment: The problem can be fixed by forcing Python to recompile the bad .pyc file. Delete the bad .pyc file and Python automatically recompiles it the next time the .py file is run. However, because of the number of .py files that a script could reference, it can be hard to track down the individual file that is causing this error. Instead delete all the .pyc files in the Python install. You can also refer to the steps given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30861493/how-to-fix-python-valueerrorbad-marshal-data)